# How can I delete files on a PDA using CMD/Batch file

Tags: windows-xp, file-management, windows-mobile, batch, pda

A customer's users are using PDAs (HP iPAQ, different models) with a CRM-Tool on it.

If the application and database need to be reinstalled there are some files in different folders on the PDA which need to be deleted first.

Usually I need to pick and delete them by hand, which costs too much time.

Is there a way to access the PDAs file system through a batch file on the PC it's connected to?

I ask this question because the PDA has no device letter such as C:\

We run Windows XP here.

*EDIT:*
I'm not allowed to install any 3rd party applications on the iPAQ. It has to be accessed from within my PC through some kind of batch or script.

Comment: An accurate answer will depend on what you mean by PDA. Are you talking about a specific model or at least a specific vendor. There would be different answers for different vendors/models.

Comment: The manufacturer is HP but there are different iPAQs in use

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of anything that runs via the PC but you could look at something like MortScript (http://www.sto-helit.de/index.php?module=page&entry=ms_overview&action=view) which is used for writing scripts to run on the PDA.

You're likely to find it can do a whole bunch of other stuff you might find useful.

Personally I wouldn't use it for production stuff but for support tasks like this it could be pretty well suited.

EDIT:  Another option might be something like this: http://www.mochasoft.dk/freeware/ftpd.htm  - a Freeware FTP server for Windows Mobile.  Again though, it requires something to be installed on the PDA.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm not allowed to install any kind of 3rd party software on the PDAs. That's why I need to do it from my PC.

Answer (score 1):

If the device can be connected to the PC as a USB Mass Storage, then it will have a drive letter and you will be able to manage its file system from batch files.

Otherwise, the only solution that comes to my mind is to write a custom tool that will use the [Remote API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa920177.aspx) functions (such as [CeDeleteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa918917.aspx)) to remotely delete files and folders on the device.

**Edit:** Or you could try [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/) - it's a freeware tool that can automate GUI actions on applications, so you should be able to create a script that will open the device in Explorer, navigate its file system and delete the files.

Comment: +1 For the AutoIt advice, we use that to customize the installation progress anyway. A "real" sollution would have been great but now I will use AutoIt. Thanks a lot. If someone else knows a way to access the iPAQ through some kind of device ID or something let me know.